# How is it that "to result" is intransitive?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Would somebody explain why the verb "to result" is intransitive? I don't understand it.

For example, we say we are dealing with **Problems resulting from errors** made in the past.

I feel that it is transitive (of course it is not and I just feel it) and I cannot understand what is the analogy between this verb and a verb like "to win" in this sentence: He won [just by one point].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intransitive verbs are verbs without a direct object. "Problems result from errors" (a sentence where the modified noun phrase in your example comes from) consists of a subject, a verb, and a prepositional phrase; no direct object.

If the sentence was *"Problems result banana from errors", it would have been transitive ("banana" being a direct object here).

Comment: Thanks, so far your answer has been of great use to me;However, I still have a problem which I'll be happy if you solve. Do you mean a prepositional phrase cannot be a direct object ever?

Comment: Not unless it has been stripped of its prepositionalphraseness (by quoting, for instance: *He yelled "above us"* means something quite different than *He yelled above us*).

Answer (score 0):

A **transitive** verb is a verb that takes one or more objects. This contrasts with **intransitive** verbs, which do not have objects. A transitive verb **transmits action to an object** and may also have an indirect object, which may indicate to or for whom the action is done.

```
 We are dealing with Problems ...
```

Here, the "problems" is the object of "deal" not the verb "result"

[Please check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb)

Answer (score 0):

To result is an intransitive verb because it takes no direct object.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/result_2

Comment: Thanks, I already have seen it's formal definition in the Longman dictionary.